# What is the difference between "information on/about" and "information of"

Tags: prepositions

All the dictionaries I have say that the word "information" is usually used in combination with "on" or "about". However, when I Googled with the phrase "information of", there were a lot of hits. For example, I found the following sentence on the Texas Tech University website:

> You cannot access your own medical information or **medical
>   information of your family**, even if they have asked you to.

Is there any difference between "information on/about" and "information of"?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=information+of%2C+information+on%2C+information+about&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinformation%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinformation%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinformation%20about%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are completely different. With *information*, in the context you gave, **of** can only indicate ownership/possession. It is otherwise incorrect.

> Information of your family

Means information *belonging to* your family.

To say information relating to something, we can use **about** or **on**. For example:

> My family has a history of diabetes

This is information *on* my family or *about* my family. We wouldn't (in most contexts) say it is information *of* my family.

It's not common to talk about information *belonging to* someone in this way, so when you use "information of [someone]", it should be very clear that the information belongs to them in a special way, for example, it is a private record with protected status (like medical records). It may be better to use a clearer way to indicate possession in this case, for example:

> information belonging to my family
>   my family's information

Another context where *information* might be followed by *of* could be when we are *describing the information itself*, for example in a phrase like

> information of a sensitive nature

This does not mean information about "sensitive nature", but describes the information as sensitive (so it might need to be kept private). Similarly:

> information of this kind is considered sensitive

This means the type of information we are talking about (such as medical records) is sensitive.