# information of case studies vs. information about case studies

Tags: prepositions

I have read [this link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/152129/what-is-the-difference-between-information-on-about-and-information-of) but still I have a problem. Which preposition is correct?

> information of case studies
>
> information about case studies

Comment: This needs more context.  Can you give us a complete sentence?

Comment: Not if you read the link. Information on or about. Never of with the meaning seen in the link.

Comment: @stangdon Table 1 summarizes the information of/about these case studies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the link you provided, *information* ***of*** means *information* ***belonging to***.

It may be possible that, at a school, information resulting from classroom case studies is stored somewhere, and that what you're interested in looking at this information.

In such a specific situation, using **of** would be correct—but it would still sound awkward because we wouldn't normally phrase it that way.

> information *of* case studies

This sounds like a mistake.

Instead, we might say:

> Please provide me with information *produced by* classroom case studies.

(Adding the *classroom* qualifier is important here, as it limits the information to a manageable and specific subset.)

---

However, it's much more likely that what's being requested is information on the *subject* of case studies. In which case, the following (including **about**) are all prepositions that can be used:

> information *about* case studies
>   information *on* case studies
>   information *concerning* case studies